# Boost program arguments can parse a wstring, but forces it into a string?

Tags: c++, boost

I am parsing command line arguments with wide strings using [`boost::program_options`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_65_1/doc/html/program_options/overview.html). I have the following code:

```
namespace po = boost::program_options;
po::options_description desc("Allowed options");
desc.add_options()
    ("silent", po::value<std::wstring>()->default_value(L"yes"), "Select the verbosity")

po::variables_map vm;
po::wcommand_line_parser parser(args);
po::wparsed_options parsedOptions = parser.options(desc).style(1).run();
po::store(parsedOptions, vm);
po::notify(vm);
```

But i get the error:

> Error C2678   binary '>>': no operator found which takes a left-hand operand of type 'std::basic_istream>' (or there is no acceptable conversion)

From the `add_options` functional line. I understand that `operator>>` and `operator<<` [don't work with `wstring`s](https://ideone.com/2W4wjy). But `boost` specifically supplies the `wcommand_line_parser` (note the w) for wide string command line argument parsing. But it doesn't look like there is a way to actually retrieve that argument result as a wide string.

Is there a work around for this or am I doing something incorrectly?

---

*Note:* The code can be compiled with this change:

```
desc.add_options()
("silent", po::value<std::string>()->default_value("yes"), "Select the verbosity")
```

But then you will lose unicode information from the string. Not sure exactly what the result will be from this conversion, or how it is done.

Comment: Try `wvalue` instead of `value`. I have a slight feeling that's what worked for me once upon a time.

Comment: @chris `wvalue` is a type. But how it will throw the same error. I think the parser is the one that cant handle it. So still no unfortunately.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need two things:

- use `wvalue`
- supply the narrow-char text representation of the default value for use in the usage description text.

  Note that you quoted the error from the `add_options` line. The problem is adding the option description, not parsing it.

  The reason is that option descriptions are `char`-based always (you knew this because the description and option names are narrow too). When getting the textual representation of the default value, Boost PO tries to use the `ostream` operator¹ and that doesn't work for your `wchar_t const*` or `std::wstring` value.

  The same happens with non-streamable custom option types, so you can pass the textual representation manually (e.g. `default_value(std::vector<int>{1,2,3}, "1-3")` for some multi-valued option that parses ranges).

### DEMO

You get:

See it **<kbd>[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/7866eaee134e9a72)</kbd>**

```
#include <boost/program_options.hpp>

namespace po = boost::program_options;

int main() {
    po::options_description desc("Allowed options");
    desc.add_options()
        ("silent", po::wvalue<std::wstring>()->default_value(L"yes", "yes"), "Select the verbosity")
        ;

    po::variables_map vm;
    std::vector<std::wstring> args { L"--silent=no" };
    po::wcommand_line_parser parser(args);
    po::wparsed_options parsedOptions = parser.options(desc).style(po::command_line_style::default_style).run();
    po::store(parsedOptions, vm);
    po::notify(vm);
}
```

> ### NOTE
>
> In this particular example you might want `po::bool_switch()` instead of `po::xvalue()`

---

¹  (eventually, via Boost Lexical Cast)